# this.props.onPress is not a function error Nativebase checkbox

Tags: javascript, native-base, vue-native

I am a newbie and exploring Navivebase components on Vue Native , I am trying to use a checkbox , where I have mixed the Nativebase component with Vue Native components. It works fine until I like the event handler function to the code , I am not able to figure out how to do it , I have attached the code below

```js
<template>
  <view class="container">
    <view>
    
    <text class="text-header">Register</text>

     <text-input
         class="text-input-login"
         v-model="firstname" placeholder="email"
       />

     <text-input
         class="text-input-login"
         v-model = "lastname" placeholder="password"
       />
      <text-input
        class="text-input-login"
        v-model = "email" placeholder="password"
      />

      <text-input
          class="text-input-login"
          v-model = "pwd" placeholder="password"
      />

      

       <touchable-opacity class = "button-container" v-bind:on-press="handleBtnPress">
          <text class="button-login">Register</text>
      </touchable-opacity>

      <nb-container class="check-box">
        <nb-checkbox :checked="agreeTnC" onPress= {this.handleCheckBox()} />
      </nb-container>

   </view>
  </view>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
 
import {APIService} from './APIService';

const apiService = new APIService();

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      firstname:'',
      lastname:'',
      email:'',
      pwd:'',
      agreeTnC:false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleBtnPress: function() {
   
      apiService.authenticate(this.email,this.pwd).then((data) => {

        console.log(data);

        result = data['result'];

        if(result == 'failed') {
          alert('Login failed, please retry with correct username and password');
        }
        
      });

    },
    handleCheckBox: function() {
        this.agreeTnC = !this.agreeTnC
    }
  }
};
</script>



<style>
.container {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #4b4463;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.button-container {
  
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width:300;
  height: 40;

  background-color: #4b4463;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 2;

  margin-top: 30;

  margin-bottom: 100;
}
.text-color-primary {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20;
  margin-bottom: 10;

}

.text-header {

  color: white;
  font-size: 40;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50;

}
.text-input-login {

 background-color: white;
 height: 40;
 width: 300; 

 font-size: 20;
 margin-bottom: 20;

}
.button-login {
    
    color: white;
    background-color: #4b4463;
}

.check-box {
    
    width: 200;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #4b4463;

}
</style>
```

I am getting following error on click of check box

[image]

Comment: change ```onPress={this.handleCheckBox()}``` to ```onPress={this.handleCheckBox}```?

Comment: @JuniusL. same issue , gives same error

Answer (score 0):

There is mistake in `onPress= {this.handleCheckBox()}`
onPress accepts function value, but you are calling the function and providing value. So it becomes `onPress= {undefined}` which is not a function.

change `onPress= {this.handleCheckBox()}` to `onPress= {this.handleCheckBox}` (without parenthesis) and it should be fixed.

Comment: try removing `this`

Answer (score 0):

following things worked for me

```
handleChange() {
    this.agreeTnC = !this.agreeTnC;

}
```

and also the component declaration was changed this way

```
 <nb-checkbox :checked="agreeTnC" :onPress="handleChange">
  </nb-checkbox>
```